# Why are these golang pointers not equal?

Tags: pointers, go

In the example below I check the equality of two pointers

- The pointers are pointing to the same address
- They are not the same pointer

How do I check if two pointers are pointing to the same address? I **do not** want to check if the contents of both pointers are equal.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Map struct {}
type Fragment struct {
    Map *Map
}

func (m1 Map) NewFragment() (f Fragment) {
    f.Map = &m1
    return
}


var m Map = Map {}

func main() {
    f := m.NewFragment()
    fmt.Println(f.Map == &m) // false
    fmt.Println(*f.Map == m) // true

}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YXwaRqYUUj)

Comment: In your code, func (m1 Map) NewFragment operates on a value and not a pointer. If you change that to func (m1 *Map) NewFragment() etc etc, the two Println will both return true. I'm not sure how you expect the program to work otherwise.

Comment: Use `==`. If the pointers point to the same variable, they have the same address. From the spec: `Pointer values are comparable. Two pointer values are equal if they point to the same variable or if both have value nil.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As JimB answered, you can use `==` to compare pointers. The reason this program behaves that way is because when you call the `NewFragment` method, a copy is made of the receiver. In this case, that means the line `f.Map = &m1` is taking the address of the *copy*, not the original object. Therefore, the pointers are different (`f.Map != &m`), and the values are the same (`*f.Map == m`).

Answer (score 4):

#### Pointers comparison

> The equality operators == and != apply to operands that are comparable.
>   Pointer values are comparable. Two pointer values are equal if they point to the same variable or if both have value nil.

This is a valid code:

```
func main() {
    s := struct{}{}
    p1 := &s
    p2 := &s
    fmt.Println(p1 == p2)
    fmt.Printf("%p, %p", p1, p2)
}
```

#### Pointer receivers

Your code has a significant mistake which actually caused the behavior you described. Method could be declared with *value receiver* `func (s SomeObj) DoSomething(){}` and with *pointer receiver* `func (s *SomeObj) DoSomething(){}`. If a method declared with value receiver (like you did) you will obtain a copy of the object but if you declare a method with pointer receiver (like you should do) you will obtain a pointer to the object itself.

Your code lacks only one asterisk:

```
type Map struct{}
type Fragment struct {
    Map *Map
}

func (m1 *Map) NewFragment() (f Fragment) { // Note, this is a pointer receiver
    f.Map = m1
    return
}

var m Map = Map{}

func main() {
    f := m.NewFragment()
    fmt.Println(f.Map == &m) // true
    fmt.Println(*f.Map == m) // true
    fmt.Printf("%p, %p", f.Map, &m)
}
```

#### Conclusion

Pointer comparison is check whether it is the same pointer (identity). So if you look closer at your code you will see that your code and my example located above have the same meaning.

Playgounds:

https://play.golang.org/p/GgTOEgvWA9

https://play.golang.org/p/kFxpu-8TDT